# Leetcode 200. Number of Islands TLE

Tags: python, depth-first-search, connected-components

Link to the question: https://leetcode.com/problems/number-of-islands/

Given a 2d grid map of '1's (land) and '0's (water), count the number of islands. An island is surrounded by water and is formed by connecting adjacent lands horizontally or vertically. You may assume all four edges of the grid are all surrounded by water.

Example 1:

Input:

```
11110
11010
11000
00000
```

Output: 1

My logic is to simply do dfs from every node and keep track of the connected components.
Am getting Time Limit Exceeded (TLE) for the 46th test case, can someone help me optimize this code?

class Solution(object):

```
def numIslands(self, grid):

    def in_grid(x, y):
        return 0 <= x < len(grid) and 0 <= y < len(grid[0])

    def neighbours(node):
        p, q = node
        dir = [(-1, 0), (0, 1), (1, 0), (0, -1)]
        return [(x, y) for x, y in [(p + i, q + j) for i, j in dir] if in_grid(x, y)]

    def dfs(node):
        visited.append(node)
        for v in neighbours(node):
            if grid[v[0]][v[1]]== "1" and v not in visited:
                dfs(v)

    components = 0
    visited = []
    for i in range(len(grid)):
        for j in range(len(grid[0])):
            node = (i, j)
            if grid[i][j] == "1" and node not in visited:
                components += 1
                dfs(node)

    return components
```

Comment: Please explain the goal and the rules here.

Comment: I just added the question and the link to it as well.

Comment: You misunderstood. By "here" I did not mean link to it. I meant explain it here, please. Questions and answers with links to external sites are considered in danger of becoming useless, if/when the external reference dies.

Comment: Oh okay got it, anyway I have added the description to the post so that will serve the purpose.

Comment: I have a feeling that you can  reduce the neigbour checking to left and up, i.e. no need for right and down.

Comment: I tried that out, but it's not working in some cases like : [["1","1","1","1","0"],["1","1","0","1","0"],["1","1","0","0","0"],["0","0","0","0","0"]]

Comment: Please [edit] to update your question with things you tried and how they worked/failed. Show the modified code and report in which way it failed.

Comment: You can try using disjoint set https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-the-number-of-islands-set-2-using-disjoint-set/

Comment: Simply iterate over the grid. Every time you find `1`  recursively change it and all its `1` neighbors to `0` and count as island.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your approach is correct. However you are using `visited` as a `list` which takes `O(n)` to search a value. So its overall time complexity is `O(N^2)`. I would suggest to use `set` rather than `list` which is a hash table.

There is just two parts to revise:

- `visited = []` -> `visited = set()`
- `visited.append(node)` ->`visited.add(node)`

I confirmed that it is accepted. Now `node not in visited` takes `O(1)` so the overall time complexity is `O(N)`.

% Like most of other LeetCode problems, the problem statement does not give any information about input data. But as your code is TLE so we can assume that we cannot solve it with time complexity `O(n^2)`.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are getting TLE is that you are using a list to keep a track of visited nodes. The search of a value in a list takes O(n) time in the worst case.

It's optimal to keep the index status of a visited/non-visited node as a 2D matrix containing boolean values or O/1 integer values. This leads to a constant access time O(1) to find the visited/non-visited status of a node.

```
class Solution {

    boolean isSafe(char[][] grid, int[][] visited, int i, int j)
    {
        int n = grid.length;
        int m = grid[0].length;

        if((i<0 || i>n-1) || (j<0 || j>m-1))
            return false;

        return visited[i][j] == 0 && grid[i][j] == '1';
    }

    void DFS(char[][] grid, int[][] visited, int i, int j)
    {
        visited[i][j] = 1; //marked visited

        int[] row = {-1, 0, 1, 0};
        int[] column = {0, 1, 0, -1};

        for(int k = 0; k<4; k++)
        {
            if(isSafe(grid, visited, i+row[k], j+column[k]))
            {
                DFS(grid, visited, i+row[k], j+column[k]);
            }
        }
    }

    int DFSUtil(char[][] grid)
    {
        int count = 0;

        if(grid == null || grid.length == 0)
            return count;

        int n = grid.length; //rows
        int m = grid[0].length; //columns

        int[][] visited = new int[n][m];

        for(int i = 0; i<n; i++)
            for(int j = 0; j<m; j++)
            {
                if(grid[i][j]=='1' && visited[i][j] == 0)
                {
                    DFS(grid, visited, i, j);
                    count++;
                }
            }

        return count;
    }

    public int numIslands(char[][] grid) {

        int result = DFSUtil(grid);

        return result;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it in Java by a DFS approach, it's simple and easy to understand.  Here, my code may help you:

```
public static int numIslands(char[][] grid) {

    int countOfIslands = 0 ;
    for (int i = 0; i <grid.length ; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j <grid[i].length ; j++) {
            if(grid[i][j] == '1'){
                DFS(grid,i,j);
                countOfIslands++;
            }
        }
    }

    return countOfIslands;

}

public static void DFS(char[][] grid , int row , int col){

    if(grid[row][col] == '0')
        return;

    grid[row][col] = '0';
     //   System.out.println("grid = " + Arrays.deepToString(grid) + ", row = " + row + ", col = " + col);
    if(row+1 < grid.length)
        DFS(grid,row+1,col);
    if(row-1 >=0)
        DFS(grid,row-1,col);
    if(col+1 <grid[0].length)
        DFS(grid,row,col+1);
    if(col-1 >= 0)
        DFS(grid,row,col-1);

}
```

Reference for if this is your first time hearing about the DFS for a graph:
[DFS Approach](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/depth-first-search-or-dfs-for-a-graph/)

Answer (score 0):

**Modified Simple DFS Solution**

```
class Solution {
public int numIslands(char[][] grid) {
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < grid.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < grid[i].length; j++) {
            if (grid[i][j] != '0') {
                count++;
                shrink(grid, i, j);
            }
        }
    }
    return count;
}

private void shrink(char[][] grid, int i, int j) {

if (i < 0 || j < 0 || i >= grid.length || j >= grid[0].length || grid[i][j] == 
'0')
        return;
    
    grid[i][j] = '0';
    shrink(grid, i, j+1);
    shrink(grid, i, j-1);
    shrink(grid, i+1, j);
    shrink(grid, i-1, j);
}
}
```